# `globals` not working inside a nested function

Tags: python

I'm making a decorator that allows me to make functions run as if their lines of code are written in main. To achieve this, I'm using `globals().update(vars())` inside the function (works), but now inside the decorator it fails.

```
class Debugger:
    @staticmethod
    def in_main(func):  # a decorator
        def wrapper():  # a wrapper that remembers the function func because it was in the closure when construced.
            exec(Debugger.convert_to_global(func))  # run the function here.
            globals().update(vars())  # update the global variables with whatever was defined as a result of the above.
        return wrapper


    @staticmethod
    def convert_to_global(name):
        """Takes in a function name, reads it source code and returns a new version of it that can be run in the main.
        """
        import inspect
        import textwrap

        codelines = inspect.getsource(name)
        # remove def func_name() line from the list
        idx = codelines.find("):\n")
        header = codelines[:idx]
        codelines = codelines[idx + 3:]

        # remove any indentation (4 for funcs and 8 for classes methods, etc)
        codelines = textwrap.dedent(codelines)

        # remove return statements
        codelines = codelines.split("\n")
        codelines = [code + "\n" for code in codelines if not code.startswith("return ")]

        code_string = ''.join(codelines)  # convert list to string.

        temp = inspect.getfullargspec(name)
        arg_string = """"""
        # if isinstance(type(name), types.MethodType) else tmp.args
        if temp.defaults:  # not None
            for key, val in zip(temp.args[1:], temp.defaults):
                arg_string += f"{key} = {val}\n"
        if "*args" in header:
            arg_string += "args = (,)\n"
        if "**kwargs" in header:
            arg_string += "kwargs = {}\n"
        result = arg_string + code_string
        return result  # ready to be run with exec()
```

example of reproducible failure:

```
@Debugger.in_main
def func():
    a = 2
    b = 22

func()

print(a)
```

Gives

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks, I hate it! (If you're doing this for fun or to see if it _can_ be done, that's awesome. If this is an alias account for one of my coworkers, please step into my office.)

Comment: @KirkStrauser Hi, I dropped to your office but couldn't find you. Thanks.

Comment: Dang it. I'd baked cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am not sure what you are trying to do. But messing with variables scope and encapsulation may yield very bad and unpredictable and undebuggable behavior.
   **I STRINGLY NOT RECOMMNED IT**.
2. Now to your problem:

`globals()` is a tricky one as there is no one `globals()` dictionary.

You can verify it easily by `print(id(globals())` and see.

What is working for your example is mutating the `__main__` module `__dict__` with the `exec` results.

This is done by `exec(the_code_you_want_to_run, sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__`.
The `globals().update(vars())` is not needed.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
class Debugger:
    @staticmethod
    def in_main(func):  # a decorator
        def wrapper():  # a wrapper that remembers the function func because it was in the closure when construced.
            exec(Debugger.convert_to_global(func), sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__)  # run the function here on the scope of __main__ __dict__
            # globals().update(vars())  # NOT NEEDED
        return wrapper


    @staticmethod
    def convert_to_global(name):
        """Takes in a function name, reads it source code and returns a new version of it that can be run in the main.
        """
        import inspect
        import textwrap

        codelines = inspect.getsource(name)
        # remove def func_name() line from the list
        idx = codelines.find("):\n")
        header = codelines[:idx]
        codelines = codelines[idx + 3:]

        # remove any indentation (4 for funcs and 8 for classes methods, etc)
        codelines = textwrap.dedent(codelines)

        # remove return statements
        codelines = codelines.split("\n")
        codelines = [code + "\n" for code in codelines if not code.startswith("return ")]

        code_string = ''.join(codelines)  # convert list to string.

        temp = inspect.getfullargspec(name)
        arg_string = """"""
        # if isinstance(type(name), types.MethodType) else tmp.args
        if temp.defaults:  # not None
            for key, val in zip(temp.args[1:], temp.defaults):
                arg_string += f"{key} = {val}\n"
        if "*args" in header:
            arg_string += "args = (,)\n"
        if "**kwargs" in header:
            arg_string += "kwargs = {}\n"
        result = arg_string + code_string
        return result  # ready to be run with exec()
```

Comment: Same error shows up. `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. Please see the example at the bottom of the question.

Comment: this is working for me. from where do you run `func()`?

Comment: I define it on the fly in the console and run it (doesn't work). If I write it in the main code it works.

Comment: well, I run it with python some_file.py and it is working. when declaring func in the prompt I get a different error from `inspect.getsource()`

Comment: i am with python 3.7